# Can you prevent P4Merge from jumping back to the top of the file when editing the workspace file?

Tags: perforce, p4merge

I have a long standing issue with P4Merge. When I diff a workspace file with the version in the depot and then proceed to edit the workspace file, within P4Merge, after every edit and save the cursor jumps back to the top of the file. This force me to navigate back to the last diff I was at.

So the steps are something like:

1. Diff workspace file with depot version
2. Edit workspace file by pressing Edit File (in right pane) button
3. Edit the workspace file
4. Save the file (ctrl+s)

The result after step 4 is that you are automatically scrolled back to the first change in the file and have to track back the change you were previously focused on.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening? I.e. I just want to stay at the current line and be able to proceed to go to the next or previous change from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not a way to prevent this -- sounds like a bug more than anything.

As a workaround you can configure other merge tools to use with Perforce.  Since you're on Windows my personal recommendation would be P4WinMerge (the merge tool that used to be bundled with P4Win -- I always found it a lot less "jittery" than the newer one so I never bothered to switch over), which you can still download thanks to the Wayback Machine:

http://web.archive.org/web/20160703111618/http://filehost.perforce.com/perforce/r07.2/bin.ntx86/p4winst.exe